# File_get_contents and fwrite with word document (images are not saved)

Tags: php, image, file-get-contents

I'm coding a script in PHP which is taking an xml document with file_get_contents, i replace some caracters with str_replace and i write this file in a Word document with a fwrite.

Exemple :

```
$myContent = file_get_contents("../ressources/fichiers/modeles_conventions/modele_convention.xml");

$lettre = str_replace("@NOMENT@",utf8_encode($data['nomentreprise']),$lettre);

$newFileHandler = fopen("../ressources/fichiers/conventions/lettre_convention_1.doc","a");
fwrite($newFileHandler,$lettre);
fclose($newFileHandler);
```

In localhost it's working but on a server the problem is :

My xml file contains images, but my final .doc document doesn't retrieves these images.

I don't understand why my images are not retrieved.

---

Well i didn't find out a solution to my problem.

I get my xml file (which is in reallity a .doc file with an .xml extension)

```
    $myContent = file_get_contents("../ressources/fichiers/modeles_conventions/modele_convention.xml");
```

I replace some stuff

```
    $myContent = str_replace("@NOM_ENTREPRISE@",stripslashes($data['nomentreprise']),$myContent);
    $myContent = str_replace("@STATUT_ENTREPRISE@",stripslashes($data['juridique']),$myContent);
```

I save my document

```
    //On génère la convention
    $newFileHandler = fopen("../ressources/fichiers/conventions/convention_".$data2['nomeleve']."_".$data2['prenomeleve']."_".$data3['idstage'].".doc","ab");
    fwrite($newFileHandler,$myContent);
    fclose($newFileHandler);
```

The xml document contains images, in localhost it retrieves images but not on the server.

exemple of xml code :

```
<w:r>
 <w:rPr>
  <w:rFonts w:ascii="Arial" w:h-ansi="Arial" w:cs="Arial"/>
   <wx:font wx:val="Arial"/>
    </w:rPr>
     <w:pict>
      <v:shape id="_x0000_i1028" type="#_x0000_t75" style="width:48.75pt;height:24pt">
       <v:imagedata src="wordml://06000003.emz" o:title=""/>
      </v:shape>
     </w:pict>
</w:r>
</w:p>
```

Comment: Unless you have PHP's automagically_convert_files extension enabled, you realise that you'r not generating a real .doc file, just telling PHP to lie to your client's browser and pretend that this XML is a Word document

Comment: I think my problem is the opposite, it's word document just saved as .xml file.

Answer (score 1):

Creating Word files using HTML is a way to let Word think that it is a Word document. Naming it .doc creates a file that is by default opened in Word. However, it isn't an actual Word document, you are faking it. It only works because Word also supports opening HTML. Other clients may not support HTML or not support all HTML entirely. For instance, the image tag does not work with TextMate on Mac, altough the bold tag works just fine.

In your XML, you must refer to the image using an absolute path, i.e. a path on the internet or a local file system path. For instance, `<img src="image.png">` will not work, since the Word file does not know how to locate it. However, you may use `<img src="http://yoursite.com/image.png">`. I'm sure that you can also refer to your local file system, with for example the `file:` 'protocol'. This only works when the file is present on the file system where the file is opened though.

If this does not solve your problem, you should probably post your XML file here.

---

However, if you are creating this for a client or external system (so anything but yourself), I'd suggest using something like:

**COM objects**
This only works when Word is actually installed on the system where the web application runs.

```
<?php 
$word = new COM("word.application") or die ("Can't create Word file"); 
$word->visible = 1; 
$word->Documents->Add(); 
$word->Selection->TypeText("this is some sample text in the document"); 
$word->Documents[1]->SaveAs("sampleword.doc"); 
$word->Quit(); 
$word->Release(); 
$word = null; 
?>
```

([source](http://www.ozzu.com/programming-forum/php-create-word-document-t65376.html))

**Office Open XML or other format**
The [new XML format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML) used by Word is open source and can be modified more easily. I don't know the exact details, but it's basically some XML files compressed into a zip file and given the extension .docx.

If possible, you can also use the ODT format of OpenOffice. Most recent Word versions can also read this file and the format is open source. It is also more feasible to create PDF files than Word files using PHP.

**phpLiveDocs**
[phpLiveDocs](http://www.phplivedocx.org/) is an extension for PHP and can be used to create Word files.

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

I don't want to use COM tools so i keep my method of file_get_content.

I didn't think about your solution to manualy put a path to local images. But i got an other problem, my document is not really an xml file because it's a word document with .xml extension so i can't specify a path to my images.

Do you think that i can transform word document to xml file? (I'll search on the web)

Comment: Maybe you should post an example of your XML file here, so we can help you. And specify what you exactly want.